# Div changes background color when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm still learning jquery and how to put it all together but I have this code set up in a shopping list:

```
<div class="AddCheckedWrapper">
    <span>Check to Add to Cart</span>
    <input name="atcuid" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

How I want this to work is using Jquery, have .AddCheckedWrapper check the checkbox and clicking it again unchecks it. Then, if the box is checked .AddCheckedWrapper background changes to blue. And if it's not checked then .AddCheckedWrapper background changes pink. The issue I'm having though is 1) I can't find coding that'll make the div check and uncheck AND have it change background colours. and 2) Since it's a list, there's more than one .AddCheckedWrapper so I know $(this) will have to be used somehow. I also have a quantity box that'll check the checkbox if you change what's in it. So if I change the number in the quantity box no matter it'll check the checkbox. So the background colors have to be in effect based off of the check box being checked or not, and that's where I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct that you can use the `this` reference of the element that raised the event to traverse the DOM and find the related `.AddCheckedWrapper`. In this case you can use the `closest()` method to find the element, then `toggleClass()`.

You can also raise the `change` event on checkbox when the quantity field in the row is changed. Try this:

```js
$('.AddCheckedWrapper :checkbox').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.AddCheckedWrapper').toggleClass('checked', this.checked);
});

$('.AddCheckedWrapper .qty').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.AddCheckedWrapper').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.value != 0).change();
});
```

```css
.AddCheckedWrapper {
  background-color: pink;
}
.AddCheckedWrapper.checked {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="AddCheckedWrapper">
  <label>
    <span>Check to Add to Cart</span>
    <input name="atcuid" type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <input name="qty" type="number" class="qty" min="0">
</div>
<div class="AddCheckedWrapper">
  <label>
    <span>Check to Add to Cart</span>
    <input name="atcuid" type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <input name="qty" type="number" class="qty" min="0">
</div>
```

Comment: I guess the OP needs to trigger `change` on checkbox, when the quantity inputs change too.

Comment: @xohbrittx If you want to increase the hit area of the checkbox, add a `label` element. I also updated the answer to show you how to check the checkbox when a quantity > 0 is entered.